# How to change “have done” into “had done”?

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, participe-passé

In French, how do you express the idea of the past perfect (had done)? In English, it is as simple as changing “has” into “had”, but how about in French?

**Elle n'a jamais rien mangé d'aussi bon.**

{ She has never eaten anything so good. }

Comment: "Elle n'avait jamais rien mangé d'aussi bon?" Changing it to Plus-que-parfait (auxiliaire => imparfait).

Comment: Well, that is a simple conjugation rule which is exactly the same as in English where you changed **has** to **had**. In French  you change **a** to **avait**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, since the only answer is a comment, I'll just steal that comment and make an answer out of it!

> Elle n'avait jamais rien mangé d'aussi bon.

Just as in English you change *has* to *had*, in French you change *a* to *avait*, the third person singular imperfect (imparfait) conjugation of *avoir* being used here to form the compound plus-que-parfait *avait mangé*.